# Can't set my theme

Tags: android, android-theme

I try set my theme for my app but I cant fix it - 
[image]

I see white color text on white background - how to change text color in `ActionBar` popup from white to black?

It's my theme:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_bg</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/edittext_primary</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/light_blue</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/white</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>

    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>

    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/WhiteDrawerIconStyle</item>

    <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>

    <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>

    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/myPopupMenuStyle</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/myPopupMenuStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="myPopupMenuStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu"></style>
<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
<item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: you have used toolbar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) inside your activity layout??

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar yes, I use ToolBar

Comment: then change popup theme in toolbar like --> app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" or whatever you want

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar pls, write as answer and I close this answer)

Comment: its ok just close this question keep stack clean :)

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar i try your solution but it doesn't help me (

Answer (score 1):

Put this Style in res,

```
    <style name="MyAppActionBarTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyApp.PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyApp.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- The beef: background color for Action Bar overflow menu -->
    <style name="MyApp.PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Bonus: if you want to style whole Action Bar, not just the menu -->
    <style name="MyApp.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <!-- Blue background color & black bottom border -->
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/blue_action_bar_background</item>
    </style>
```

And, of course, in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/MyAppActionBarTheme" 
    ... >
```

What you get with this setup:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this theme, if you are using android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar,

it will solve your problem.

```
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```